# Crystal Report Group Record Number

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, grouping

I am working on C# Crystal Report 2013. I want this type of report
With serial number from 1 in each group. So how should I do this?

```
Group - Dept A
1 - 123 Abc
2 - 234 Xyz
3 - 445 Pqr

Group - Dept B
1 - 344 uuu
2 - 322 989
```

Comment: i have created groups but i want the numbering format that each group record should start from 1.

Comment: Just create another group for Serial number under Dept group. And suppress the Details section. Place all fields on the Serial No group. You will get what you want.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it follow below way.

create a formula `@reset`

```
Shared Numbervar count;
count:=0;
```

Place above formula in group header and group footer.

Create one more formula `@Count` to count and place it where requreid.

```
Shared Numbervar count;
count:=count+1;
count
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do it follow below way.

-Add running total field.

-Field to Summarize => a field of your group which you want to count

-Type of summary => Select "count".

-In evaluate select => For each Record

-Reset => On Change of Group (select your group)

-Place it on Details section

Answer (score 3):

1. Add running total field.  Give it proper name.
2. Field to summarize  : Select group column name to summarize.
3. Type of summary : Select "count".
4. In evaluate select "On Change of Group".
5. Reset : select "Never".

Comment: Simple and Easy. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

place reset formula in the section you want to rest the serial count

```
@reset formula

Shared Numbervar count;
count:=0

@increment formula

Shared Numbervar count;
count:=count+1;
count;

@display group footer formula

Shared Numbervar count;
Shared Numbervar Count_Final;
Count_Final:=Count_Final+count;
count;

@final report footer formula
Shared Numbervar Count_Final;
Count_Final
```